# Why result of matrix multiplication with Eigen is different from standard vector matrix with c++?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

At the same time, I multiply two matrix using Eigen and standard C++. But the results are not the same, though very similar. For example, matrix a and b are C++ style, and matrix c and d are Eigen style. Now the sum of a*b and c*d is the same, but each coeff is not the same. For later derivation calculation, the different result will generate different results. I do not the reason. And I check all the details but no problem can be found.

Comment: Floating point arithmetic does not give exact results, and as a result different ways of doing the same computation can give different final answers.

Comment: @lixiang, this question was answered [here](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=119907#p303319), if you don't understand it, please be more specific.

Comment: Because the result will be used for calculating the derivation in back propagation in neural network application. So it will influence the following result much.By comparing the two results from Eigen and C++, the final converge result will be very different where the initialization is the same.

Comment: The results returned by naive for loops or Eigen are different, but you cannot tell which one is more accurate. So you must fix your algorithm to make it robust to rounding error. For instance have a look at this tool to automatically measure the divergence: http://www-pequan.lip6.fr/cadna/